# Exporting Tensorflow model to Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-ml-engine

I am trying to export my model to *Google Cloud Storage*. I used `tf.contrib.learn` to build my model and followed the iris classification example.

After my training and evaluation is done I would like to store the model on the cloud so I can make predictions, but I don't know how to export the model.

```
classifier = tf.contrib.learn.DNNClassifier(feature_columns=feature_columns,
                                            hidden_units=[100],
                                            n_classes=50,
                                            model_dir="Model_Logs")
```

Comment: There are several Iris examples floating around. Can you point to which one you are using. In addition, can you specify if you are training on cloud ml engine or locally? Either is fine, but potentially affects the answer

Comment: I am training on the cloud. Here is the iris example I followed https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/tf learn. I only used it as a template. I have hosted my data on the cloud and was able to train my model. I am just having trouble exporting.

Answer (score 0):

The best example of training on the cloud is probably [census (canned estimator)](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/census/estimator/trainer) or [census (custom estimator)](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/census/customestimator/trainer). They use the same Estimator API, so that part should be familiar. In addition, they use the `Estimator` class to help perform the training automatically. The `train_and_evaluate` method is called on that class by `learn_runner.run`, which will export the model if properly configured, which basically boils down to setting the [`export_strategy`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/f92eb6043cde550ba1791a54b86509e50753a4c9/census/customestimator/trainer/task.py#L203) and the [`model_dir`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/f92eb6043cde550ba1791a54b86509e50753a4c9/census/customestimator/trainer/task.py#L208)

If you want to do things outside the `Experiment` and `learn_runner` frameworks, you can just call [`Estimator.export_savedmodel`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/88d648f3beedfa6123efabb756be372f69382983/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.py#L1223)